# SQL Server 2005: Insert one to many (1 Order-Many Charges) results into @table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a list of Orders

**Orders**

```
OrderID     CustomerID      ProductID
-------------------------------------
1           32              15
2           16              28
3           7               20
4           32              16
```

and a list of charges which need to be applied to these Orders

**Charges**

```
ChargeID    CustomerID      ProductID   Charge  Desc
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1           32              0           8.99    Basic Cost Per Order
2           32              15          10.05   Subcharge: Delivery
3           16              28          8.99    Basic Cost Per Order
4           16              0           16.05   Subcharge: Delivery
5           7               20          17.99   Basic Cost Per Order
```

Note:

In `charges`, if a `ProductID = 0`, it means that the charge will be applied to all products.

e.g.

- Charge 1 - the `8.99` will apply to all `Products` for Customer 32
- Charge 2 - the `10.05` will only apply to product `ID=15` for Customer 32

Thus:
`OrderID = 4` will not have the *Subcharge Delivery* since the *ProductID* is not found for *customer 32*

Question is :
How do I fill the `@tempQuote` table with quotes for these orders?

The required resultset in this case would thus be:

```
OrderID ChargeID
--------------------
1       1
1       2   
2       3           
2       4
3       5
4       1
```

The problem is that I just can't simple insert the *OrderIDs* into the `@tempQuotes` table, and then apply charges, because there could be multiple charges and then I get the error

> *Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , > >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression*

Gold medal would obviously have been if there were some means of :
if there are multiple charges, then for each multiple charge insert the *orderid/chargeID* into the `@tempQuotes` table
e.g. 
Update the `@tempQuotes` table if there is only 1 row, or if there are multiple charges then
insert each Order/Charge
OR
save into a `@tempQuotes` additional column all the *ChargeIDs* that apply e.g.

```
OrderID, ChargeID
1        1,2
```

as opposed to updating the charges like for e.g.

```
 Insert into @tempQuotes(OrderID)
select OrderID from #Orders

Update  t
set ChargeID = (Select #Charges.ChargeID from @tempQuotes t
inner join #Orders on t.OrderID = #Orders.OrderID
inner join #Charges on #Orders.CustomerID = #Orders.CustomerID)
from @tempQuotes t

select * from @tempQuotes
```

Setup of tables:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
drop table #Orders
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Charges') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
drop table #Charges
END


create table #Orders(
OrderID int identity(1,1),
CustomerID int,
ProductID int,
)
Insert into #Orders(CustomerID,ProductID) values (32,15)
Insert into #Orders(CustomerID,ProductID) values (16,28)
Insert into #Orders(CustomerID,ProductID) values (7,20)
Insert into #Orders(CustomerID,ProductID) values (32,16)


create table #Charges(
ChargeID int identity(1,1),
CustomerID int,
ProductID int,
Charge     decimal(10,2),
[Desc]     nvarchar(50),
) 
Insert into #Charges(CustomerID,ProductID,Charge,[Desc]) values (32,    0,  8.99,   'Basic Cost Per Order')
Insert into #Charges(CustomerID,ProductID,Charge,[Desc]) values (32,    15, 10.05,  'Subcharge: Delivery')
Insert into #Charges(CustomerID,ProductID,Charge,[Desc]) values (16,    28, 8.99,   'Basic Cost Per Order')
Insert into #Charges(CustomerID,ProductID,Charge,[Desc]) values (16,    0,  16.05,  'Subcharge: Delivery')
Insert into #Charges(CustomerID,ProductID,Charge,[Desc]) values (7, 20, 17.99, 'Basic Cost Per Order')

declare @tempQuote table(
OrderID int,
ChargeID int
```

)

```
declare @tempQuote table(
OrderID int,
ChargeID int
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT O.OrderId, C.ChargeId
FROM Orders O
  JOIN Charges C ON O.CustomerId = C.CustomerId AND
    (C.ProductId = O.ProductId OR C.ProductId = 0)
ORDER BY O.OrderId, C.ChargeId
```

Here is the sample [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88339/1).

And it produces these results:

```
ORDERID   CHARGEID
1         1
1         2
2         3
2         4
3         5
4         1
```